# How to copy vb.net project with linked files

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net windows application project and I want to make another project base on the first project and modify some forms or reports.

The scenario is, copy entire project as link then delete forms/reports that I want to modify then create the same form/report name that I want to modify, by doing this I only maintain one source code on most of them.

I don't want to do this one by one by adding existing item and Add as link, I have tried to create a solution with many projects and drag folder from base project to new project with 'Alt' key pressed with no success

I have read somewhere to edit project file something like this:

> _Inlined\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)

but it makes vs 2012 not responding

Comment: OK, I found it, I just created a second project then edit projj file, add something like this

<Compile Include="..\SourceFolder\*.*;..\SourceFolder\class\*.vb"
 Exclude="..\SourceFolder\bin\Debug\*.*"> 
 <Link>_Inlined\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link> 
</Compile>

then open the project and viola, all linked files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new project based on the first project, my suggestion is to copy the entire project folder and then rename.

Once you do this, you will have two identical projects with the same linked files, meaning that if you want to edit the new one, it would be exactly like editing the new one.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough what I want, The second project will have linked files (forms, module, class etc) to first project,  only changes will be in second project. So I only need maintain one source code (most of them)